# Running code and get segmentation fault error

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int size;

    cout << "How many vertices? \n";
    cin >> size;

    while (size > 20 || size < 0) {
    cout << "Error. Enter new number: ";
    cin >> size;
    }

   int graph[size][MAX_VERTICES],x,y;
   InitializeGraph(graph, size);
   while(x != 0 || y != 0) {
   for(int i = 0; i<= size; i++){
     cout << "Enter a vertex pair(0 0 to end): ";
     cin >> graph[x][y];
    } 
   }
}
```

When I run this code in my program, I get a segmentation fault error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's `graph`? How do you declare and initialise it? If it's an array or vector, then you need to check that `x` and `y` are within range before using them as indexes.

Comment: Please post what `graph` is declared as, and what the values of `x` and `y` are when the crash occurs.

Comment: You never change x and y so if they are not 0 then you are getting an infinite loop.

Comment: Does that help? I added the rest of the code from main

Comment: How and where do you initialize `x` and `y`?

Comment: Are you supposed to be reading the `x` and `y` values (as the prompt suggests)? Or a value to put in the graph? Or all three? As it is, you're using uninitialised variables as array indexes, which will be disastrous.

Comment: You didn't post the *values* of `x` and `y`.  Are you debugging your code?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is have the loop prompt the user to enter in vertices. If they type in 0 0 the program will then get out of the loop and continue the rest of the program. Those are my intentions.

Comment: You're also using a variable-length array, which isn't standard C++. If `MAX_VERTICES` is too large, then the array might be too big for the stack. This code is a minefield of undefined behaviour, so it's hard to guess exactly what's making it crash.

Comment: @a07b30d: So that would be `cin >> x >> y;` to read the values. Then presumably you set `graph[x][y]` to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare local (non-static) variables, they will not be initialized and their values will be*indeterminate* (in reality they will be seemingly random). Using such a variable except to initialize it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), one of the most common causes of crashes.

What you are doing is writing to random locations in memory by using those uninitialized variables as indexes of the arrays.

---

What you seem to want to do is read first the x and y values, and then read a value into that position.

I would suggest something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(size, std::vector<int>(MAX_VERTICES));
unsigned int x, y;  // No negative numbers allowed

while (true)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter two vertices (end with any being 0): ";
    if (std::cin >> x >> y)
    {
        if (x > size || y > MAX_VERTICES)
        {
            std::cout << "Those vertices are to big, pleas try again\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (x == 0 || y == 0)
            break;  // End of input

        std::cout << "Please enter a value for (" << x << ',' << y << '): ";
        // -1 because the indexes entered by the user are 1-based,
        // vector indexes are 0-based
        std::cin >> graph[x - 1][y - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        if (std::cin.eof())
            break;  // User terminated input by end-of-file
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter two integer values equal or larger than zero.\n";
            std::cin.clear();  // Clear the error, and try again
        }
    }
}
```